# Does Apache Camel create multiple threads for multiple from() inside configure() in 3 server nodes?

Tags: apache-camel, integration, camel-ftp

If we deploy following camel code in three Wildfly nodes:

```
configure(){
   from("sftp").to("MyQueue")
   from("MyQueue").to("database")
}
```

How does program execute in all three nodes?

Does it creates 6 threads i.e 1 thread for from("sftp") - Polling and 1 thread for from("queue") for listening to sftp response.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the SFTP consumer, but 1 sounds coherent **because an SFTP endpoint does not support concurrency**.

Said that, you should **take care** when you run multiple Camel applications that consume from the same FTP endpoint. Otherwise you will get lots of errors because they compete against each other about the same files.

For a JMS consumer you can **configure the number of concurrent consumers** when you configure the broker connection.